# error on a dojo grid when adding new item to the store

Tags: dojox.grid

I'm stuck with a problem on a dojo grid when adding new item to the store.
I've got :

1. a dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid containing articles
2. a tabcontainer where the tabs represent article's family.

Each time I choose a tab , it filters the grid to display that family, so far everything work fine.

But I've a button that allows to add a new article to the grid through a new window.
If the grid is not filtered no problem , but if i've got a tab selected I get the error:
**grid assertion failed in itemwritestore**
Same error on FF and IE, I search internet for that error but i didn't find anything revelant.

---

My code if its helps ...

```
                var grid=parent.registry.byId('lagrid');
        var items=lagrid.store._arrayOfAllItems;
        var item=items[e.rowIndex];
        var lestab=parent.registry.byId( 'TabContainerRayon');
        var tabsel=lestab.selectedChildWidget.id
        var ongletR=tabsel.substring(1,tabsel.length);
        if (grid)
        {
            var storeParent=grid.store;
            var itemsParent=storeParent._arrayOfAllItems;
            for (i=0 ; i< itemsParent.length ; i++)
            {
                if (itemsParent[i].col17==idLigne)
                {
                     alert("Article déjà présent");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            var myNewItem = {
            id: grid.rowCount+1,
            col2:trim(lagrid.store.getValue(lagrid.getItem(e.rowIndex),"Col5")),
            col3:undefined,
            col4:undefined,
            col5:trim(lagrid.store.getValue(lagrid.getItem(e.rowIndex),"Col6")),
            col6:trim(lagrid.store.getValue(lagrid.getItem(e.rowIndex),"Col8")),
            col7:undefined,
            col8: undefined,
            col9: undefined,
            col10: 1,
            col11: undefined,
            col12:trim(lagrid.store.getValue(lagrid.getItem(tabInd[0]),"Col1")),
            col13:trim(lagrid.store.getValue(lagrid.getItem(e.rowIndex),"Col2")),
            col14:'<A HREF="javascript:addProduit('+ (grid.rowCount)+');" ><IMG border=0 SRC="/'+CheminBase+'/Flag_White.gif"></A>' ,
            col15: ongletR,
            col16:"<a href=\"javascript:afficheImg("+grid.rowCount+",'"+trim(lagrid.store.getValue(lagrid.getItem(e.rowIndex),"unid"))+"')\"><img src='/" + CheminBase + "/pictures.png?OpenImageResource' border=0></a>",
            col17:idLigne ,
            col18:trim(lagrid.store.getValue(lagrid.getItem(e.rowIndex),"Col9"))
            };

            parent.PctPrixTolere.push(parseInt(lagrid.store.getValue(lagrid.getItem(e.rowIndex),"Col7")));
            parent.PresenceReleve.push("0");
}
        // ajoute l'item dans le store
        grid.store.newItem(myNewItem);
        grid.store.save();
        parent.registry.byId('external').hide();
```

---

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

ok I finally find my mistake thanks to ie debugger :)
in fact I was using **grid.rowCount+1** to identify my new item, but if I click onto a tab, I have always less row than the store has => same id than an existing row => assertion failed. I changed that to **grid.store._arrayOfAllItems.length** and it works fine :)